# Label Ordering in Scipy Dendrogram

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

In python, I have an N by N distance matrix dmat, where dmat[i,j] encodes the distance from entity i to entity j. I'd like to view a dendrogram. I did:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

labels=[name of entity 1,2,3,...]

Z=linkage(dmat)
dn=dendrogram(Z,labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

But the label ordering looks wrong. There are entities which are very close from dmat, but that's not reflected in the dendrogram. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) must be either the distances in *condensed* format, or the array of points being clustered.  If you pass the square (N x N) distance matrix, `linkage` interprets it as N points in N-dimensional space.

You can convert from your square matrix to the condensed form with [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html).

Add this to the beginning of your file

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
```

and replace this

```
Z=linkage(dmat)
```

with

```
Z = linkage(squareform(dmat))
```