# scipy hierarchy.linkage and Bray-Curtis distances not consistent

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, skbio

I am working with a set of species counts (counts) from several different sample stations (stations). I have calculated the Bray-Curtis similarity between every possible pair of sample stations using the pw_distance function from scikit-bio. This produces a distance matrix with values bounded between 0 and 1. So far so good.

I want to use that distance matrix to produce a dendrogram showing how the sample stations cluster together. I am doing this using scipy's hierachy.linkage function to find the linkages for the dendrogram, and then plotting with hierarchy.dendrogram.

Here's my code:

```
from skbio.diversity.beta import pw_distances
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

bc_dm = pw_distances(counts, stations, metric = "braycurtis")

# use (1 - bc_dm) to get similarity rather than dissimilarity
sim = 1 - bc_dm.data

Z = hierarchy.linkage(sim, 'ward')
hierarchy.dendrogram(
    Z,
    leaf_rotation=0.,  # rotates the x axis labels
    leaf_font_size=10.,  # font size for the x axis labels
    labels=bc_dm.ids,
    orientation="left"
)
```

[here is a link to the dendrogram produced by the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxd1U.png)

As I understand it, the distance on the dendrogram should correspond to the Bray-Curtis similarity (analogous to a distance), but the distance values on my dendrogram reach a maximum of over 30. Is this correct? If not, how can I scale my distances to correspond to the Bray-Curtis similarity between sample stations? If it is correct, what do the distances on teh dendrogram really correspond to?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700628/scipy-cluster-hierarchy-labels-seems-not-in-the-right-order-and-confused-by-th/40707534#40707534, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331537/label-ordering-in-scipy-dendrogram/48331999#48331999, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416498/dendrogram-or-other-plot-from-distance-matrix/41418241#41418241, or ... (it is a common issue, reflecting a confusing API).

Answer (score 1):

See the links shared in the comments as they address your questions.

One `scikit-bio` step that isn't covered in those links is that you should call linkage on `bc_dm.condensed_form()`, rather than on `bc_dm` or `sim`. This will get you the input in the format that you need. If you pass a 2D matrix, `linkage` assumes that it's your `counts` matrix, and is computing Euclidean distances between your samples based on those data.

Also, be sure to pay attention to the `method` parameter to `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` as that will impact the interpretation of the branch lengths in your dendrogram. The doc string for `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` contains details on how these are computed for the different methods.